# Spring Boot DevTools in IntelliJ - Initialization error

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

I'm using Spring Boot, Java 17, IntelliJ version 2019.2.4, and Spring Boot DevTools.

However, upon initialization, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:103)
    ... 5 more
```

The error doesn't occur if I initialize it through debugging or if I remove the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency.

**pom:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sounds like an intellij bug given the stack trace.

Comment: The error seems to be a compatibility issue between **IntelliJ IDEA's** older version and the newer version of **Spring Boot** with **DevTools**. This can be seen from the part of the Stack Trace that references: `com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:103)`. Possible fixes: Upgrade **Intellij IDEA**, Check for outdated plugins, reimport the project, clean and rebuild and reconfigure the **DevTools**.